# Excel Timer Function Throwing "Expected Function or variable" Error

Tags: excel, timer, pause, vba

I have an Excel macro I've called for years I need a pause in running code. Here's the macro:

```
Sub timeFrame(PauseTime As Double)
'
Dim Start As Double
Start = timer
    Do
        DoEvents
    Loop Until (timer - Start) >= PauseTime

End Sub
```

I just ran a macro that calls the one above and got an "Expected Function or variable" compile error with the *Start = time* line highlighted. In troubleshooting, I established that the error occurs with any macro that contains the same line. I even went to [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/VBA/Language-Reference-VBA/articles/timer-function) and copied their sample code, and got the same error when I tried to run it.

I thought I might have a missing library reference but nothing showed up there. After an hour or so of Googling I'm at a complete loss for a reason for the error, and would greatly appreciate some fresh insight.

Comment: Have you created a `Sub` called `Timer` within your project?  That's the error that would occur if you had.

Comment: Duh. I'd have never thought of that. Thanks so much!

Answer (score 0):

This can happen if you have a Function or Sub that shares the same name as the Module. Every name must be unique. Even the Modules.